# Center JTEXTAREA Gridbag

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, gridbaglayout

I'm looking to center the JTextArea I have in the bottom of my swing application.
I've been playing with the coordinates of the gridbag layout, but cannot seem to figure out how to extend the JTEXT AREA to fill up the space under the enter button. 
[image: gui]

```
package guiprojj;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.json.parsers.JSONParser;
import com.json.parsers.JsonParserFactory;


public class gui {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame maingui = new JFrame("Gui");
        maingui.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        maingui.add(enter, c);
        final JTextArea movieinfo = new JTextArea(5,20);
        movieinfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2,2,2,2,Color.red));
        final JTextField movietext = new JTextField(18);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        maingui.add(movietext, c);
        final JScrollPane scrolll = new JScrollPane(movieinfo);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 4;
        maingui.add(scrolll, c);

        final JLabel titlee = new JLabel("Enter movie name below!");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        maingui.add(titlee, c);
        maingui.setResizable(false);
        maingui.setVisible(true);
        movieinfo.setLineWrap(true);
        movieinfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        movieinfo.setEditable(false);

        scrolll.getPreferredSize();
        //pangui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        //pangui.add(scrolll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //movieinfo.add(scrolll);
        maingui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        maingui.pack();
        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
            {
                System.out.println(Test.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText()));
                 JsonParserFactory factory=JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
                 JSONParser parser=factory.newJsonParser();
                 Map jsonData=parser.parseJson(Test.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText()));
                 String Title = (String)jsonData.get("Title");
                 String Year = (String)jsonData.get("Year");
                 String Plot = (String)jsonData.get("Plot");
                 movieinfo.setText("Title: "+Title+"\nYear: "+ Year +"\nPlot: "+Plot);
            }
            });

        }
}
```

Comment: Read the link to Swing tutorial that you were given in you last question related to this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876646/creating-gridbag-layout/18876704#18876704). Did you read the section on spanning cells? Also you are allowed to use more than one layout manager. Since you haven't thanked anybody for the help given there, I'm not about to spoon feed you an answer again.

Comment: you have to insert something like a flow layout in row 1 and the `JTextArea` in row 2. I suggest you to use `BoxLayout` that in my opinion is better, please read this answer of mine for explanation.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835198/positioning-of-components-how-to-place-a-few-buttons-center-screen-same-size/12837118#12837118 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774432/jframe-not-the-right-size-when-its-executed-any-reason-why/12780478#12780478

Comment: @camickr My apologies, I had plans of thanking people for helping me.

Comment: @EricLang, and yet you still haven't accepted either of the answers here either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding gridwidth constraint like below:

```
    final JScrollPane scrolll = new JScrollPane(movieinfo);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 4;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    maingui.add(scrolll, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use the [constructor of `JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea%28%29) that doesnt specify the number of rows & columns
- Set `fill` property for `GridBagConstraints` to `BOTH`
- Set non-zero `weighty` for expansion along Y axis, e.g. `c.weighty = 1`